# Comparing the front elements of a queue using the >= operator

Tags: java, queue, operators

This is a typical stack permutation with the help of 2 queues, one for input and the other for output. I wish to check if the q2 (output) is the correct permutation of q1 (input), but I can't compare the front elects of 2 queue because of their type `Object` as the `>=` operator won't work on it.

```
package a2;
import a1queue.*;
import a1stack.*;

public class Permu {

    public static int stperm(ArrayQueue q1,ArrayQueue q2) throws EmptyStackException, QueueFullException, EmptyQueueException, StackFullException{

    ArrayStack s = new ArrayStack();


    while(!q2.isEmpty()){
        while(!q1.isEmpty() && q2.front() >=q1.front() ){// shows error here

            if(q2.front() == q1.front()){
                System.out.println("enqueue(q2,dequeue(q1))-> "+ q1.front() + " is enqueued in q2.");
                q1.dequeue();
                q2.dequeue();
                                        }

            else {
                System.out.println("push(s,dequeue(q1)) -> " + q1.front() + " is pushed into stack.");
                s.push(q1.dequeue());

                }


        }
        if (q2.front() == s.top()){
            System.out.println("enqueue(q2, pop(s)) "+s.top() +" is popped from stack & enqueued in q2.");
            s.pop();
            q2.dequeue();

        }
        else{
            q1.enqueue(s.pop());
            System.out.println(s.top());
            break;


            }


    }
    System.out.println("it is a permutation");
    return 0;


}



private static int compare(java.lang.Object front, java.lang.Object front2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}



private static int Object(Object front) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}



public static void main(String[] args) throws QueueFullException,StackFullException,EmptyQueueException,EmptyStackException {


     ArrayQueue q1 = new ArrayQueue();
     ArrayQueue q2 = new ArrayQueue();


    q1.enqueue(1);
    q1.enqueue(2);
    q1.enqueue(3);
    q1.enqueue(4);
    q1.enqueue(5);
    q1.enqueue(6);

    q2.enqueue(4);
    q2.enqueue(5);
    q2.enqueue(3);
    q2.enqueue(2);
    q2.enqueue(1);
    q2.enqueue(6);

    System.out.print( stperm(q1,q2));
}
}
```

Comment: Why not make the queues generic? I see you are adding integers, so Queue<Integer> will return an Integer that you can compare.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your objects `Comparable`.

```
public class Obj implements Comparable<Obj>
{
...
}
```

and then specify an attribute to compare. With respect to what you want to compare your objects? Based on their IDs? Based on their names?

Notice that you cannot use operators in Java to compare. You should invoke `compareTo()` method that you should define in a `Comparable` object.